# i am using voce my programme compiles succesfully but i am getting error occured initializing vm can not find native libraries

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, speech-to-text, voice-recognition, voce

this is my code i am using vs2013. i have set dependencies and all the linkers but still my code compiles correctly but when cosole opens it says error initializing vm, unable to find native libraries

```
#include <iostream>
#include <voce.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "jvm.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "jawt.lib")
using namespace std;
int main()
{
init("C:\\voce-0.9.1\\lib\\", false, true, "C:\\voce - 0.9.1\\lib\\gram", "digits.gram");`

string s;
// Speech recognition in C++
while (voce::getRecognizerQueueSize() > 0)
{
s = voce::popRecognizedString();
        cout << "You said: " << s << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Voce is really really old, try something different.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev any suggestions?

Comment: Microsoft Speech API is pretty good on Windows, you can also try Google speech API and some open source packages.

Comment: any code example for SAPI or google speech api?